# Looking for a way to correcly generate an iptables-restore file

Tags: firewall, iptables, python-iptables

I'm building a firewall rule generator and i need to apply all the iptables rule atomically. The only guaranteed way to do that is to use an iptables restore file, which has it's own syntax. The only guaranteed way to generate such a file is to run the iptables commands, dump them with iptables save and restore them, which seems completely unacceptable for a live system. Is there an easier way, such as a software which will parse raw iptables rules and generate an iptables restore? I've found [fwmacro](https://github.com/keesbos/fwmacro), but it's not maintained, and has it's own syntax, such as:

```
-A 10stateful -mstate --state INVALID -j DROP
```

instead of

```
iptables -A stateful -mstate --state INVALID -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to generate an `iptables-restore` file is to run `iptables-save > rules.ipt` and then edit the file with any required statements.